# Sampling the derivative of an inverse of a function

Tags: calculus

Assume I have in hand a real smooth function $f(t)$ which I know is invertible but I can't calculate its inverse. Sampling the inverse, though, is very easy: generating $x_k,y_k$ pairs of $f^{-1}(x_k)=y_k$ can simply be done with $x_k=f(y_k)$. My question is as follows: given $f$ explicitly together with all its derivatives, can I generate triples of $x_k,f^{-1}(x_k),(f^{-1})^{\prime}(x_k)$ (means, also the value of the inverse's derivative at the point $x_k$) rather than just pairs without derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the chain rule.

A tacit assumption is that since $(f^{-1})'$ exists, the inverse $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, and for the result to pull through, you need furthermore that $f'$ is non-zero at the points $y_k$.

Since $f(y_k) = x_k$, we get by the chain rule that

$$(f^{-1}\circ f)'(y_k) = (f^{-1})'(f(y_k))f'(y_k).$$

Notice that the left hand side is just the derivative of the identity map, which is itself, and so $(f^{-1}\circ f)'(y_k) = \text{id}(y_k)=y_k$. Hence

$$(f^{-1})'(x_k)=(f^{-1})'(f(y_k))=\frac{y_k}{f'(y_k)}.$$

To generate the triple $(x_k,f^{-1}(x_k),(f^{-1})'(x_k))$, you can thus generate the pair $(x_k,f^{-1}(x_k))$ by $x_k = f(y_k)$, and then plug the value of $y_k$ into the formula above to also generate $(f^{-1})'(x_k)$.

Comment: thanks, yes, this way i can generate pairs of $x,f^{-1}\prime(x)$ but how can i know $f^{-1}(x)$ on this case, to complete the triple? i cant access it directly

Comment: @TroyMcClure I had some typos, which I've corrected, and I've added a comment in the end.

Comment: but to plug into the formula i need to be able to compute either the inverse or its derivative, right?

Comment: @TroyMcClure You have that $(f^{-1})'(x_k)=\frac{y_k}{f'(y_k)}.$, and you wrote that the derivative $f'$ is available, so I assumed you would be able to calculate $f'(y_k)$.